# why does code below return Null rather than "0123456789"

Tags: python

This is my code. If s = "0123456789", why does code below return Null rather than "0123456789"

```
def longestDigitsPrefix(s):
    res = ''

    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit() is True:
            res = res + i
        else:
            return res
```

Comment: `return` not in the first `if` clause. in other words you never return when `i` is a digit. also just do `if i.isdigit()`, you do not need to compare `True` to `True`. `i.isdigit()` should already be `True` or `False`

Comment: Looks like your trying to add an [int] to a [string].

Answer (score 1):

because all of the s is digit then your only the first block of if statement get executed, so you need another return statement too:

```
def longestDigitsPrefix(s):
    res = ''

    for i in s:
        if i.isdigit() is True:
            res = res + i
        else:
            return res
    return res
```